# NTLM authentication in flutter web. options?

Tags: flutter, ntlm, flutter-web, flutter-plugin

I have successfully used https://github.com/mrbbot/ntlm for authentication is iOS... but, after working through some CORS issues, I realize that it doesn't work for flutter web.  I created an issue just in case, but I thought there might be some other ways to approach this. Are there any other options?

This is the error the I got when running ntlm_client.get("url"):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(dartx.contains)' of null
    at http.NTLMClient.new._ntlm (http://localhost:50126/packages/ntlm/src/http.dart.lib.js:84:80)
    at _ntlm.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:37175:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:37029:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:32116:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:32663:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:32701:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:32544:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:32566:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:37290:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:37296:13)
    at http://localhost:50126/dart_sdk.js:32918:9
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: I updated the question to show the error message

Comment: I don't have required things configured but you can try to debug it if it's urgent. I suspect there is some issue in getting the header in line 92.`!res0.headers[HttpHeaders.wwwAuthenticateHeader].contains("NTLM"))`.

Comment: yeah... I'm trying to debug... but really, I'm hoping for any other solution.  This package isn't meant for flutter web (at least, that's how it's tagged on pub.dev) but, besides CORS, I don't see why it would behave differently on web versus iOS

Comment: Did you check what's happening on the line 92? What's there in headers?

Comment: I did.  there's nothing in the headers, in fact, there's nothing but res0.bodybytes when I do it with Chrome. (however, I get other properties when it's with iOS)

Comment: it looks like it diverges on line 96 of http.dart... with ios it gets a full response, with Chrome, it's missing some pieces

Comment: So I think the header itself is not there for a webapp and it's just trying to extract and check if it has a particular keyword i.e. NTLM. I don't think if it's an issue with `http` package. Just check if you have any specific configuration at the server for iOS devices and why the header is not sent for webapp. Try to hit using POSTMAN

Comment: the http.dart package I was talking about is inside ntlm.  The server is ok... it's something with the package.  I created an issue for that package... but, so far, I think his package is the only one that exists for ntlm.